# Python, Pandas Dataframe get the index back after a group by

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by, dataframe

I'm having a Pandas DataFrame named 'class_price_df':

```
                           email                   cat           class
0               trangthanhtin@yahoo.com     Mobiles & Tablets      1
1                    concomai@yahoo.com     Mobiles & Tablets      4
2                   yenvo.ier@gmail.com     Mobiles & Tablets      2
3                   quyenvy71@yahoo.com     Mobiles & Tablets      4
```

I'm grouping by 'email' and by 'cat' to have the max of 'class':

```
class_price_df = class_price_df.groupby(['email','cat']).max().unstack('cat').fillna(0)
```

But the output is:

```
cat                               Computers & Laptops  Consumer Electronics   
email                                                                         
+coicon7879@gmail.com                               2                     0   
+haiphong82lk@yahoo.com                             0                     2   
+nguyentrungchanhbd@gmai.com                        0                     0   
-abc@gmail.com                                      0                     0   
001kukuku@gmail.com                                 0                     4   
002pnk@gmail.com                                    1                     0   
007.heineken@gmail.com                              4                     0   
007.leson@gmail.com                                 0                     0
```

How can I get my 'index' back and have an output similar to:

```
                email                 Computers & Laptops        Consumer Electronics
0      +coicon7879@gmail.com                   2                             0  
1      +haiphong82lk@yahoo.com                 0                             2 
2      +nguyentrungchanhbd@gmai.com            0                             0   
3      -abc@gmail.com                          0                             4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `reset_index` method:

```
class_price_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks, but when I'm doing class_price_df.columns I have MultiIndex(levels=[[u'class', u'email'], [u'Automotive & Gadgets', u'Cameras', u'Computers & Laptops'.......) how can I get Index([u'email', u'Automotive & Gadgets', u'Cameras', u'Computers & Laptops'.........) ?

Comment: @user1754181 you can specify a level when you call `reset_index` using an int or the string name: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index   so `class_price_df.reset_index(inplace=True, level='class')` for example

Comment: thanks @EdChum but I still have MultiIndex(levels=[[u'class', u'email'], [u'Automotive & Gadgets', u'Cameras', u'Computers & Laptops'